# Suppress stderr console output but keep exit code in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, console, exit-code

is there a way how I can suppress the console output of sdterr but keep the exit code?

I did

```sh
#!/bin/sh
command 2> /dev/null
STATUS=$?
```

but that way, even the exit code is suppressed (and turns into `0`).

I want to achieve that I can get when a command fails without clustering the console unless a `--verbose` flag is enabled but it should quit the program when a command fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, this actually works and I had a mistake elsewhere in my script.

Today I also learned that assigning a variable also counts as a "command" and thus the exit code remained 0